# Vaadin 24 - How To Use Login Project in Multiple Other Vaadin Projects

Tags: vaadin, vaadin-flow

I have a Vaadin 24 LOGIN project that works great. It accesses the database, does all the Spring Security goodness and then goes to the default route ("/").

I have another Vaadin project that has an ADMIN UI that allows the user to perform CRUD commands for managing the users.

I have a third Vaadin project the performs some BUSINESS function.

All the applications are working GREAT by themselves.

I want to be able to use the LOGIN application in both the ADMIN and BUSINESS applications - so I don't have to copy all the same login code into both projects.

In my LOGIN application I've modified the build in the POM so that it will build two jar files - the "fat" executable and the "thin" non-executable:

```
<!-- UPDATED MAVEN TO CREATE 2 JARS, ONE EXECUTABLE AND ONE "PLAIN" -->
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>build information</id>
            <goals>
                <goal>build-info</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
        <execution>
            <id>repackage</id>
            <configuration>
                <classifier>exec</classifier>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

I also removed the `AppShellConfigurator`  from the main class in the LOGIN application.

I then made the LOGIN jar a dependency in the ADMIN application.

The part where I get stuck:

1. How do I "trigger" the `LoginView` that lives in the LOGIN project from the ADMIN application?
2. Once a successful login has been accepted - will it just redirect to the "/" of whatever main applicatin (e.g. ADMIN or BUSINESS) specifies or ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vaadin scans by default all packages below your `@SpringBootApplication` for Routes, Components and other configurations.

To let Vaadin find and automatically register your LoginView that resides in another package you have to add the package to the `@EnableVaadin` annotation.

Example:

```
@EnableVaadin(value = {"com.example.login", "com.example.app"})
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }
}
```

More information can be found in the [official documentation](https://vaadin.com/docs/latest/integrations/spring/routing).

Comment: @Knookie - thanks very much! When I do that - it's throwing an error that it can't find the datasource URL (that is defined in the LOGIN application for the LOGIN stuff). I also have the security configuration in the LOGIN file - to indicate that it should user the LoginView.class. Do I need to move the security configuration into the ADMIN solution - or ?

Comment: If all of those configurations are common between the apps, those can be in the common / login package as well.

Comment: OK - thanks. That's what I was expecting. However it's not finding the driver class (this is defined in the application.properties of the LOGIN app. Will @EnableVaadin read that properties file as well - or do I need to make a separate class that defines the DB connection in the LOGIN app?

Comment: The class only takes care of Vaadin related annotations.

Comment: OK - thanks for pointing me in the right direction Knoobie! Just to be clear - it WILL allow the other Spring annotations to be processed as well - right? Or do I need to use:  @ComponentScan(basePackages = {"com.example.from.jar"})