# Vaadin's MainView seems to be unrecognized if moved to a different package from the one where my Springboot Application is

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, vaadin

I'm currently experimenting with Vaadin, so I've decided to start a Spring project and I was trying to build a UI. So far I've organized my packages this way:

```
main
  └── java
        └── com.asta
                  ├── ui
                  │       ├── client package with Vaadin files (com.asta.ui.views, com.asta.ui.components, etc.)
                  │
                  └── server
                          ├── config
                          │       └── Configuration classes (Spring configurations, security configs, etc.)
                          │
                          ├── controllers
                          │       └── All controllers (SquadraController, GiocatoreController, etc.)
                          │
                          ├── entities
                          │       └── All JPA entities (Squadra, Giocatore, etc.)
                          │
                          ├── repositories
                          │       └── All JPA repositories (SquadraRepository, GiocatoreRepository, etc.)
                          │
                          ├── services
                          │       └── All service classes (SquadraService, GiocatoreService, etc.)
                          │
                          └── util
                                  └── Utility classes, if any.
```

Now, my SpringbootApplication and my MainView classes are in com.asta.server, but if i move the last one to the ui package, it doesn't work anymore. Is there a way to allow MainView to be in a different package?

I've tried working with annotations and googling my problem with no results so far.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/76757037/1662997